# Llega el email, pero con los campos que ha rellenado el usuario vacios

Tags: php, html, html5, formularios

buenas, tengo este problema con mi formulario al momento de poner enviar reviso mi correo u¿y me llega un mensaje pero con los campos vacíos alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
adjunto código

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address= $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'ruizhermosilla@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

y mi codigo del formulario es el siguente:

```
 <form name= "sentMessage" " method="post" action="contact_me.php">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
<p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Mensaje *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
<p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
 <div id="success"></div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar mensaje</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recibir los valores de tu formulario deberías poner el atributo `name`

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nombre *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                        ^^^^  
    ...

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                         ^^^^
<!-- y así con todos -->
```

Y luego compruebas mal en la condición `if () {}`:

Tienes que poner `!` delante del `empty()` para que te devuelva `true` en caso que no este vacío y convertir `||` en `&&` para que todas las condiciones sean `true`, ejemplo:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])        &&
   !empty($_POST['email'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['phone'])       &&
   !empty($_POST['message'])     &&
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

   // Enviar mail
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, con tu ayuda pude solucionarlo